# Minecraft cannot put custom background

Tags: java, user-interface, minecraft

I am making a custom minecraft client. For it i want to make a custom main menu, i try the code:

```java
@Override
    public void drawScreen(int mouseX, int mouseY, float partialTicks) {
        // draw a image
        mc.getTextureManager().bindTexture(new ResourceLocation("moon/gui/background.jpg"));
        this.drawModalRectWithCustomSizedTexture(0, 0, 0, 0, this.width, this.height, this.width, this.height);
        super.drawScreen(mouseX,mouseY,partialTicks);
    }
```

And then replace **GuiMainMenu**(which is the default Minecraft main menu class) with **CustomMainMenu**(which is my Main Menu Class) I then try to run it, and it results in 2 pink and black boxes which mean the background file which is bg.jpg was not found. This is confirmed by the console output which says java.io file not found. I wanted it to show my background image but it did not.

A few things I tried:

- Re-downloading java
- Changing the background image
- changing the background image package from **MOON.gui** to **moon.gui** and **moon** and back to **moon.gui**
- Asking for help in a Minecraft client making [discord server](https://discord.gg/n2CzJUuhX9).

The whole code of my CustomMainMenu class is:

```java
package me.debug.moon.ui;

import net.minecraft.client.gui.*;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.GlStateManager;
import net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation;

public class MainMenu extends GuiScreen {
    // create a override drawScreem
    @Override
    public void drawScreen(int mouseX, int mouseY, float partialTicks) {
        // draw a image
        mc.getTextureManager().bindTexture(new ResourceLocation("moon/gui/bg.jpg"));
        this.drawModalRectWithCustomSizedTexture(0, 0, 0, 0, this.width, this.height, this.width, this.height);
        super.drawScreen(mouseX,mouseY,partialTicks);
    }

    // create override super initGui
    @Override
    public void initGui() {
        this.buttonList.add(new GuiButton(1, this.width / 2 - 40, this.height / 2 - 40, 200, 20, "Single-Player"));
        this.buttonList.add(new GuiButton(2, this.width / 2 - 15, this.height / 2 - 15, 200, 20, "Multi-Player"));
        this.buttonList.add(new GuiButton(3, this.width / 2 + 10, this.height / 2 + 10, 200, 20, "Settings"));
        this.buttonList.add(new GuiButton(4, this.width / 2 + 40, this.height / 2 + 40, 20, 20, "Exit"));
        super.initGui();
    }

    //create super override actionPerformed
    @Override
    protected void actionPerformed(GuiButton button) {
        switch (button.id) {
            case 1:
                this.mc.displayGuiScreen(new GuiSelectWorld(this));
                break;
            case 2:
                this.mc.displayGuiScreen(new GuiMultiplayer(this));
                break;
            case 3:
                this.mc.displayGuiScreen(new GuiOptions(this, this.mc.gameSettings));
                break;
            case 4:
                mc.shutdown();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

My file structure is: [image: File Structure]

Comment: Can you show your project structure ?

Comment: The assets folder or the code folder @Elikill58

Comment: both, something like [that](http://prntscr.com/1zwfg9v)

Comment: is this good? https://i.imgur.com/kAv8ZXe.png @Elikill58

Comment: let me make an answer. Just, can you include this screen in your question ?

Comment: im assuming your talking about the file structure @Elikill58

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said "the file is not found". This can be caused by multiple things :

- File not in plugin (**Seems to be your case**)

*How to fix:*

You should check that they are in good package. In your case, they should be on `src/resources`, but you wrote them somewhere else. So, **move it to `src/resources/moon/gui/bg.jpg`**

- Not exported in runned jar

*How to fix:*

It depend of what your are using between maven/gradle/something else, and with their config. But by default, all content of `src/resources` is included in jar.

- Not enough permission to read file

*How to fix:*

You have to check why you don't have permission, and add "read" perm. On linux for example it's with [chmod](https://www.howtogeek.com/437958/how-to-use-the-chmod-command-on-linux/) command.

Comment: When you said 
' You should check that they are in good package. In your case, they should be on src/resources, but you wrote them somewhere else. So, move it to src/resources/moon/gui/bg.jpg'
Thats **not** how it works, the resources folder for minecraft clients is for the minecraft textures, shaders, sounds(basically every thing that minecraft **requires**) rather than the gui, but i did still test it and it still did not work and resulted in a file not found error again.

Comment: Oh yes. You should put the entiere `assets/minecraft` in the src/resources

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @Elikill58 but I tried your method for putting the assets folder in the resources folder and it worked! Thanks

Comment: No problem ! And take your time, it's not a problem x)